# css grid: grid gap 1px has different size with columns and rows

Tags: css, css-grid

I am using css grid in my layout and want 1px gap bewteen grid items and around items as well so I decided to give container background color and 1px padding, 
in result you can see that between some items gap is clearly bigger than 1px. what is the problem ?

OS windows 10

**chrome**:

[image]

**firefox**

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  background: #555;
  padding: 1px;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.item {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.item:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I test this I can clearly see a 1px gap, nothing more, nothing less. Can you take a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Can you provide a screenshot, it is rendering right for me.

Comment: All gaps are the same. Can't reproduce the problem using your code. http://jsfiddle.net/0dg3wvsL/2/

Comment: chrome 68 on windows 10, same result with firefox 61.0.2

Comment: added screenshot